WebkitSpeechRecognition stops recognition when the another tab is using it simultaneously
When one tab is using the webkitSpeechRecognition API, it works well. However, when I open the same URL in another tab simultaneously, the speech recognition stops functioning without throwing any error. Why does this happen, and is there any fix for it?
I have been trying to find a fix for this issue for a while. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it to make it work?
